# Zeta zeros from prime product

Tags: number-theory

Is appears that $$\prod _p^n \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{p}-\frac{2 \cos (n \log p)}{\
\sqrt{p}}}\right )^{-1}\approx  \left|  e^{i t \vartheta \
}\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right)\right|$$

[image]

```
Plot[{Product[
     1/Sqrt[1 + 1/Prime@p - 2 Cos[t Log[Prime@p]]/Sqrt@Prime@p], {p, 
      t}], Abs[RiemannSiegelZ[t]]}, {t, 0, #}, AspectRatio -> 1/10, 
   ImageSize -> 860, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.005], 
     Point[Table[{N@Im[ZetaZero[t]], 0}, {t, 
        Floor[(11 Pi - 4 # + 4 # Log[#/(2 Pi)])/(8 Pi)]}]]}] &[100]
```

Where does this come from?